# How do I access my iCloud Drive folder from Terminal?

Tags: terminal, icloud, osx-yosemite

I'm running OS X Yosemite. I would like to save my code folder in iCloud Drive so that it's automatically backed up. I need to access files from the Terminal often, so how can I access iCloud Drive from the Terminal?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
cd ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com\~apple\~CloudDocs/
```

I would just add a symbolic link either to this folder or to a `Source` subfolder in your home directory to make working with this easier.

For example:

```
ln -s ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com\~apple\~CloudDocs ~/iCloud
```

and/or

```
ln -s ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com\~apple\~CloudDocs/Source ~/Source
```

Comment: Following this advice, I found my Mac didn't have a ```Mobile\ Documents``` folder. A little further searching revealed it in my local area, so if you cannot find it, make sure your path is ```~/Users/Local/Library/Mobile\ Documents/etc..```

Answer (score -1):

It´s in the Library Folder of the user. The folder-name is "MobileDocuments".

Answer (score -1):

It's in `~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com\~apple\~QuickTimePlayerX/Documents/...`.

How to find it? You can **drag** a file in the finder and **drop** the file to the terminal, then the file path would be displayed in the terminal.

This is an awful way to get the path, I'm very curious about how to reveal it more naturally and easily and gracefully.